# Reason for perpetual dynamic DNS updates?

Tags: dns, bonjour

(Crossposted from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/222008/40795))

I'm using dynamic DNS (the "adult" version from RFC 2136, not à la DynDNS), and for a while now I've been seeing my laptops with MacOS 10.6.x churning out updates about every 10 seconds. And seemingly redundant updates at that, as the IP is more or less stable (consumer broadband). I don't remember seeing that frequency in the (distant...) past.

The lowest time-to-live that MacOS pushes on the entries is 2 minutes, so I have no clue what's going on.

```
...
Jan 12 13:17:18 lambda named[18683]: info: client 84.208.X.X#48715: updating zone 'dynamic.foldr.org/IN': deleting rrset at 'rCosinus._afpovertcp._tcp.dynamic.foldr.org' SRV
Jan 12 13:17:18 lambda named[18683]: info: client 84.208.X.X#48715: updating zone 'dynamic.foldr.org/IN': adding an RR at 'rCosinus._afpovertcp._tcp.dynamic.foldr.org' SRV
Jan 12 13:17:26 lambda named[18683]: info: client 84.208.X.X#48715: updating zone 'dynamic.foldr.org/IN': deleting rrset at 'rcosinus.dynamic.foldr.org' AAAA
...
```

Additionally, I can't find out what triggers the updates on the laptop-side. Is this a known problem, and how would I go about debugging it? One of the machines is freshly purchased and installed. The only "major" change was installation of the [Miredo](http://www.deepdarc.com/miredo-osx/) client for IPv6/Teredo, but even disabling it didn't make a change (except that AAAA records are no longer published).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, must have been something transient: I noticed that the SOA didn't change, and after a zone freeze/thaw, the problem suddenly disappeared. Looks like BIND might have had a hick-up.